# How to access main UIViewController from UITableView RowSelect Event Monotouch?

Tags: c#, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, subclass

I have a UITAbleView on my main ViewController. Tableview is subclasses as seen below. When a user selects a row I want to switch to a new view by calling a routine on the main ViewController. However, i'm not able to access my main viewcontroller from the subclass. How should I go about this?

```
public class TableSource : UITableViewSource
{
    string[] tableItems;
    string cellIdentifier = "TableCell";

    public TableSource(string[] items)
    {
        tableItems = items;
    }
    public override int RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, int section)
    {
        return tableItems.Length;
    }
    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(cellIdentifier);
        if (cell == null)
            cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellIdentifier);
        cell.TextLabel.Text = tableItems[indexPath.Row];
        return cell;
    }

    public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        new UIAlertView("Row Selected", tableItems[indexPath.Row], null, "OK", null).Show();
        tableView.DeselectRow(indexPath, true);

        //Call routine in the main view controller to switch to a new view

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I happened to come across this post after finding and commenting on a similar post:
[Xamarin UITableView RowSelection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231303/xamarin-uitableview-rowselection)

While passing an instance of your UIViewController to your TableSource is one way to solve this problem, it does have its drawbacks. Mainly that you've tightly coupled your TableSource to that particular type of UIViewController.

What I would suggest instead is to create an EventHandler in your UITableViewSource like so:

```
public event EventHandler ItemSelected;
```

I would also set up a getter property for the selected item:

```
private selectedItem
public MyObjectType SelectedItem{
    get{
        return selectedItem;
    }

}
```

I would then update the RowSelected method like so:

```
public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    selectedItem = tableItems[indexPath.Row];
    ItemSelected(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Your UIViewController could then listen to the ItemSelected event and do whatever it needs. This allows you to reuse your UITableViewSource for multiple Views and ViewControllers.

Comment: Agreed, while passing the view controller into the constructor of your table source does have its advantages (i.e. easy access to the view controller and accessible outlets), the main disadvantages are tight coupling and testability. This suggestion of raising an event is ideal, as it decouples your table source from the view controller, and will allow you to test the data source without needing a dependency on the view controller.

Answer (score 1):

Add it to your .ctor, e.g.

```
public TableSource(string[] items)
```

becomes:

```
public TableSource(string[] items, UIViewController ctl)
```

then keep a reference to it:

```
public TableSource(string[] items, UIViewController ctl)
{
    tableItems = items;
    controller = ctl;
}
```

and use it in your `RowSelected` call:

```
public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    new UIAlertView("Row Selected", tableItems[indexPath.Row], null, "OK", null).Show();
    tableView.DeselectRow(indexPath, true);
    controller.DoWhatYouNeedWithIt ();
}
```

Comment: Hmmm.I added the changes but it is not exposing my routine which is set to public in main view.

Comment: If it's your own method then it's not in `UIViewController` but in your own subclass. You'll need to change the .ctor signature (and backing field) to match your type.

Answer (score 1):

**NSNotifications** might be another option.

So in the RowSelected you post a notification:

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.PostNotificationName("RowSelected", indexPath);
```

And in the view controller you add an observer for the notification:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();    
    NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(new NSString("RowSelected"), RowSelected);
}

void RowSelected(NSNotification notification) 
{
    var indexPath = notification.Object as NSIndexPath;
    // Do Something
}
```