# Xamarin UITableView RowSelection

Tags: iphone, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have a simple `UITableView` and I am loading the data by implementing `UITableViewSource`. I also have a label on the same page. I would like to display the selected row from tableview on label.
This is my `MainViewController`:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();
    List<string> lstTableSource = new List<string> ();
    for (int intCounter=0; intCounter<5; intCounter++) 
    {
        lstTableSource.Add ("Row "+intCounter);
    }
    tblTest.Source = new TableSource (lstTableSource.ToArray());
}

public void Test(string strSelected)
{
    lblTest.Text = strSelected;
}
```

This is my row selection method in `TableSource.cs`

```
public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    MainViewControllerObj.Test (tableItems[indexPath.Row]);
}
```

When i tap on the row system is throwing NullReferenceException on

> lblTest.Text = strSelected;

Program works fine if I print the value of the variable `strSelected` on a Console.

Comment: where is lblTest declared and instantiated?

Comment: Instead of passing a reference of the parent controller to your Table Source, it may be better to create an event that the Table Source dispatches. You can then have your controller listen for this event and access the selected item via a getter you define on the UITableSource.

This would lead to better decoupling that would allow you to use the UITableSource for more than one UIController.

Comment: @Jason label is added from xib.

Comment: @BenBishop thanks for the suggestion. I will definitely make a try.